# Плавное раскрытие div-а

Tags: html, javascript

Добрый день! Есть такой скрипт, который скрывает форму-блок, а при клике на ссылку показывает её, вопрос в том как сделать показ скрытого блока плавным, чтобы после клика форма-блок плавно разъезжалась, нужно желательно то что есть модифицировать, без привлечения библиотек. Вот то, что есть сейчас:

```
function toggleInformer()   
{       
// ищем нужный нам тег информера
var elm = document.getElementById("informer");

    // если тег найден, обрабатываем его
if(elm)
{
    // меняем видимость элемента на противоположную
    if(elm.style.display == "block")
    {
        elm.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML= '+ развернуть ↓';
    }
    else
    {
        elm.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML= '- спрятать ↑';

    }

}
```

}

и html

```
<div id="reg">
<a id="button" href="#" onclick="toggleInformer(); return false;"> Регистрация</a>
 <div id="informer">
  тут форма
 </div>
</div>
```

Я думаю, что нужно что-то тут `elm.style.display` указывать время нужное на раздвижение и т.д.

Подскажите, пожалуйста:)

Comment: Может element.style,opacity циклом крутить от 0 до 1? Всё это будет настолько сложно, при подключении JQuery эта задачка решится одной строчкой: $('#informer').fadeIn(500);

http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/EEgu7/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Т.к. сейчас уже 2013 год, большинство браузеров поддерживают [CSS3 Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions), поэтому используйте их: http://jsfiddle.net/FtL6G/

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!