# Плавно сдвинуть содержимое блока

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как мне сделать так, чтобы все что находиться снизу плавно сдвинулось вниз до тех пор пока длина того блока который выдвигается при клике не вылезет полностью...

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle(hidden_content)">ОТКРЫТЬ СТРИМ</a>
<div class="stream_block" id="hidden_content" style="display: none;">

</div>
<script>
function toggle(el) {
el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'
}
</script>

тут половина html кода, в общем половина сайта... 
нужно что бы все вниз сдвинулось плавно пока не откроется до конца блок.

.stream_block {

    width:800px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#333333;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться jquery и slideToggle();
А можно подобным образом, как уже писали тут [как раскрыть блок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/247996/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-div-%D0%B0):
http://jsfiddle.net/FtL6G/